# i m trying to return list<object> from webmethod but gives error

Tags: asp.net

System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type WebService.Property.Property_Users was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write8_ArrayOfAnyType(Object o)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ListOfObjectSerializer.Serialize(Object objectToSerialize, XmlSerializationWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues, Stream outputStream)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()

```
public List<object> GetDataByModuleName(string ModuleName)
    {
       List<Property_Users> obj_UserList = new List<Property_Users>(); 
      // performing some operation that add data to obj_UserList

     List < Object > myList = new List<object>();
            return ConvertToObjectList<Property_Users>(obj_UserList); 
    }
     public List<Object> ConvertToObjectList<N>(List<N> sourceList)
        {
            List<Object> result = new List<Object>();

            foreach (N item in sourceList)
            {
                result.Add(item as Object);
            }
            return result;
        } 

     [WebMethod]
        public List<object> GetDataByModuleName(string ModuleName)
        {
            List<object> obj_list = new List<object>();
            obj_list = BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleName(ModuleName);
            return obj_list;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The serializer cannot serialize `object`

If you are going to return a list of arbitrary type, you must `Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute` to give the serializer a hint.

Also, the list must be homogenous, containing elements of only one type. e.g. you cannot return a list containing a `Foo` and a `Bar`

Comment: is ther any other way i can do it, my list<object> is not homogenous, because i have to return the List<object>

Comment: @girish - You can try to use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute on your methods. One for each expected type. But I cannot guarantee that the serializer will accept it. Give it a shot.